# Exclude objects from scroll easing

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, web-applications

I am developing a HTML5 App with PhoneGap, that has a long page as front with scrolling enabled. Default on mobile phones (iPhone at least), when you scroll to the top, the content kind of eases out (the best description I could come up with). Because PhoneGap uses the browser, my header will also be subject to this easing, which I do not want.

Is it possible to allow the easing for some HTML objects, but not others?

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery-mobile. But generally in most Mobile-UI framework there should be a widget/header option of setting the header to a fixed position at the top. This allows the content too scroll and the header to remain fixed at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File -- you can control whether or not your page allows overscroll by adding this to your `config.xml` file:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

That won't stop your page from scrolling, of course -- you'll almost certainly still need to fix your header at the top of the page in order to get a native experience. Furthermore, you'll almost certainly want to keep the native overscroll behavior for your long text areas, so use this in your CSS for elements that need to maintain native scroll behavior:

```
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

---

**Added 9/4/2014:**

---

Here's my typical DOM structure:

```
<div class="ui-container">
  <div class="ui-navigation-bar"> Title of View </div>
  <div class="ui-scroll-container"> Long Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

In the above structure, the navigation bar is fixed at the top of the screen with CSS similar to this:

```
.ui-navigation-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 44px;   /* height: 64px; padding-top: 20px; for iOS 7, assuming border-box sizing */
    z-index: 9; /*use transform: translateZ(9px) if using 3D transforms*/
}
```

It's worth mentioning that `ui-container` is also positioned absolutely:

```
.ui-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Finally the scrollable content receives this:

```
.ui-scroll-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: tough;
    padding-top: 44px; /* avoid navbar; iOS 7: 64px */
}
```

This fixes the header to the top of the screen (or next positioned parent), and places it above the scrollable content. The scrollable content is in its own `div` which ensures it scrolls (and bounces) separately from all other content, thus preserving the native feel.

> It's important to note you could use `top:44px` instead of `padding-top: 44px` -- the reason I use padding is because I often apply a gradient to the navigation bar to simulate iOS7's blurred bars. It's not native-perfect, but it does allow for iOS 7's under-scroll or for opacity effects.

Comment: Yes. That is also what I have done now, but then there is no "easing" when scrolling to the borders, hence the users get no feedback that something is indeed happening. Does that explanation make sense? I still want the easing effect, but not for the header.

Comment: I added some more to the answer -- hopefully it helps, assuming I understood you correctly.